# C# loops about exponential numbers

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

I am new on C#, i just learned loops.

I want to write loops that run this.
(75 times)

1. step1  1^1
2. step 2 1^2+2^2
3. step 3 1^3+2^3+3^3
4. step 4 1^4+2^4+3^4+4^4
5. ...

I tried this way.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 75; i++)
{
   int sum = 0;
   for (int p = 1; p <= i+1; p++)
   {
      Math.Pow(p, (i + 1));
      sum = sum + p;
   }
  Console.WriteLine(sum);
}
```

Where am I doing wrong and how should I do about it?

Comment: What is wrong with the code you have provided?

Comment: I can not get the result I want.

Comment: Hint: you're ignoring the result of `Math.Pow`. But please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ - saying "I can not get the result I want" isn't nearly as useful as *showing* the result you want and the result you get...

Comment: Also note that you'll overflow the bounds of `int` pretty quickly...

Comment: _"I can not get the result I want."_ - In what way is the current result wrong? Please be specific in your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pow will not modify the value of p. You need to get the returned value into another variable. pp for example.

```
pp = Math.Pow(p, ...
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you're looking for.

```cs
for (int power = 1; power <= 75; power++)
{
    double sum = 0;
    for (int baseNum = 1; baseNum <= power; baseNum++)
    {
        sum += Math.Pow(baseNum, power);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(sum);
}
```